# How is the bracket question on topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This question [Custom Wood Shelf Brackets](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/custom-wood-shelf-brackets) is just asking about the brackets themselves. The wood shelf is only part of this that is wood related. That fact is not pertinent to the question.

I guess it is borderline but we closed one of these before. It was about making a brace to hold open a window. That was closed but more because it was a smithing question.

Wood shelves is something that comes up but the focus here was metal working.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to think your right, but I really wanted to answer that question!  Mostly because I felt that just bending a piece of 1/8" metal without a strut would become a disappointment...

I could use some help getting Blacksmithing and metal work off the ground so we can move these types of questions over there!

Comment: So we are ok with it mostly because it has nowhere else to go?

Comment: @Matt probably not.  Feel free to vote to close that one (off topic, not woodworking).  I will abstain.